# What is wrong with my regex in finding unnecessary char before "void main"

Tags: javascript, regex

MUST RETURN **TRUE:**

```
kword_search = wvoid main
kword_search = a ew void  main
kword_search =      wvoid main
kword_search = o       void main
```

MUST RETURN **FALSE**

```
kword_search = void main
kword_search =  void    main
kword_search =   void     main
```

What i've done so far:

```
if( /^[^v]*[^\sv][^v]*[void|int]\s+main$/.test(kword_search) ){
    alert('found unnecessary char(s) before keyword main');
}
```

the condition will be tested as kword_search last word is 'main' that's why i included $. I didnt get inside my condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to search for the conditions you accept, and error on anything else, with this regex:

```
^\s*void\s+main$
```

Use it like this:

```
if( /^\s*void\s+main$/.test(kword_search) == false ){
    alert('found unnecessary char(s) before keyword main');
}
```

Comment: True but i need it that way specifically for me to have no trouble in the latter comparisons. tnx

Comment: how could i also integrate void or int?

Comment: You would just use an alternation instead of `void`: `^\s*(?:void|int)\s+main$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^kword_search =\s{1,}void\s{1,}main
```

[Link](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Ekword_search%20=%5Cs%7B1,%7Dvoid%5Cs%7B1,%7Dmain&input=kword_search%20=%20wvoid%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20a%20ew%20void%20%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20%20%20%20%20%20wvoid%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20o%20%20%20%20%20%20%20void%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20void%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20%20void%20%20%20%20main%0Akword_search%20=%20%20%20void%20%20%20%20%20main)

So for your JS it would look like

```
if( /^kword_search =\s{1,}void\s{1,}main/.test(kword_search) == false){
    alert('found unnecessary char(s) before keyword main');
}
```

**How it works**

`^` means start of a line, so we begin with that.  `kword_search =` just searches for that.  `\s{1,}` mean at least 1 space (or `\s` matching character) but up to infinity.  `void` is just that, but since it immediately follows the `\s` there cannot be a character before it. `\s{1,}main` is the same as `\s{1,}void` but void is switched with main.

Comment: how can i apply that in my condition above?

Comment: @fireflieslive Updated.  I'll update more to explain what is happening.

Comment: `+` could be used instead of `{1,}`

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up character classes and alternation.

```
[void|int]
```

Matches a single one out of these characters: `d`, `i`, `n`, `o`, `t`, `v`, `|`. What you want is grouping:

```
/^[^v]*[^\sv][^v]*(?:void|int)\s+main$/
```

Note that you don't really need to exclude thos `v` characters before the alternation:

```
/^.*\S.*(?:void|int)\s+main$/
```